# What word describes a word that is invented ad-hoc based on popular culture?

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

I sometimes hear people use ad-hoc invented adjectives which are based on a cultural reference; a sort of fabricated synonym. What are these words called?

For example:

- “Cesar-esque” to describe someone who is like Cesar.
- “Night-manager-esque” to describe a certain style of cinematic introduction.

Answer (score 1):

You could call these examples of a *neologism*, which is defined in the Oxford dictionary as "a newly coined word or phrase".

Comment: There's another term, but it's not coming to me right now.  A bit more metaphorical.

Comment: @HotLicks -  A ***nonce*** word?